# Native Xamarin.IOS App with MVVMCross and Storyboard not working

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I created a new MVVMCross Native project, migrated it to v6.2.2. Created a single view called HomeView similar to https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarinios-ui-project

The xib page has only one `UITextField` and `UIButton`. However after the app starts I get the following exception
`Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[HomeView _setViewDelegateContentOverlayInsetsAreClean:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe8edc3cd70`

My `HomeView.cs` file is as follows:

```
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public partial class HomeView : MvxViewController
{
    public HomeView() : base("HomeView", null){}

    public HomeView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle){}

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #region View lifecycle
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
        set.Bind(TextField).To(vm => vm.Text);
        set.Bind(Button).To(vm => vm.ResetTextCommand);
        set.Apply();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: The "unrecognized selector sent to instance" often means that you have an IBOutlet incorrectly linked to your viewcontroller. Try deleting all your IBoutlets, and re-creating only one of them

Comment: Did you create the view yourself manually or did you copy a view and changed it to fit your needs?